# Laravel, using SQL with "AND" operator, with conditions

Tags: php, sql, laravel, if-statement

I've been stuck onto a problem with laravel, since I'm new to this I try things, and things still don't work.

I have a search function that, seek through the users, using the name, the specialty of the user, or his location, the function work if you fill just one input, if you start to fill a second input, it shows the first condition which is coded in the controller.

Exemple :

if i put

Name : -empty-
Specialty : -empty-
Location : New

It shows me everyone that lives in cities starting with "New", but if I do

Name : Maria
Specialty : -empty-
Location : New

It shows me everyone whose name is Maria, or, I want "Maria" who live in cities starting with "New"

So I search how to make my code work with that, making if inside of if, making double condition, but since I'm with laravel I have trouble doing it (my version is 5.0, i'll go for update after this bug is resolved)

Here is the part where I'm stuck on, with the things I tried,

```
if($attributs['specialty'] != "") {
        $users = User::where('status_user', '=', '1')
        ->where('specialty_id', $attributs['specialty'])
        ->where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$attributs['locality'].'%')  //;
      /*  if($attributs['name']!= ""){
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($name){
                $query->where(('CONCAT(lastname, " ", firstname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%')
                ->orWhere(('CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%');
            })
        }
        ->where('address', 'LIKE', '%'.$attributs['locality'].'%')
        ->where(DB::raw('CONCAT(address, " ", postal_code, " ", city)'), 'LIKE', '%'.$address.'%')*/

        ->confirmed()
        ->get();
    }

    else if($attributs['name'] != ""){
        $users = User::where(function ($query) use ($name) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($name) {
                $query->where(DB::raw('CONCAT(lastname, " ", firstname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%')
                    ->orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%');
            })
            ->where('status_user', '=', '1')
            ->confirmed();
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($name) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($name) {
                $query->where(DB::raw('CONCAT(lastname, " ", firstname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%')
                    ->orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%');
            })

            ->where('status_user', '=', '1')
            ->where('invite', '=', '1');
        })

        ->get();
    }


    else if($attributs['address'] != ""){

        $users = User::where('status_user', '=', '1')
        ->where('address', 'LIKE', '%'.$attributs['locality'].'%')
        ->where(DB::raw('CONCAT(address, " ", postal_code, " ", city)'), 'LIKE', '%'.$address.'%')
        ->confirmed()
        ->get();
    }
```

Thanks in advance, it's been days since I'm on it ><

Edit : Here's a few more info since it isn't not that clear, sorry about that

I want to make multiple search, the code I present you works, but do not provides multiple search, i tried to make if with multiple condition, and it don't work, i tried to make several where clause with if inside of the first if, and it don't work either, so here I am, thanks a lot in advance, but I'm still stuck ^^'

Comment: I don't now the last version of laravel, but i think your issue is normal, because when you pass on your condition `else if($attributs['name'] != "")` it doesn't pass on your loop with the address, so you just have the result with the name and not the address.

Comment: SQL injection warning.. `DB::raw()` need to be manually protected with `DB::escape()` for example.

Comment: Yeah, sure, this thing is normal, but I try to make it work with more than one condition, and making if(condition1 && condition2){} don't even work

Answer (score 0):

Try `when()` conditional operator. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses

```
$users = User::when($attributs['specialty'] != "", function($q){
                      return $q->where('status_user', '=', '1')
                              ->where('specialty_id', $attributs['specialty'])
                              ->where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$attributs['locality'].'%')
                              ->confirmed();
                    })
                    ->when($attributs['name'] != "", function($q){
                      return $q->where(function ($query) use ($name) {
                                  $query->where(function ($query) use ($name) {
                                      $query->where(DB::raw('CONCAT(lastname, " ", firstname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%')
                                          ->orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%');
                                  })
                                  ->where('status_user', '=', '1')
                                  ->confirmed();
                              })
                              ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($name) {
                                  $query->where(function ($query) use ($name) {
                                      $query->where(DB::raw('CONCAT(lastname, " ", firstname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%')
                                          ->orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname)'), 'LIKE', $name.'%');
                                  })

                                  ->where('status_user', '=', '1')
                                  ->where('invite', '=', '1');
                              })
                    })
                    ->when($attributs['address'] != "", function($q){
                      return $q->where('status_user', '=', '1')
                              ->where('address', 'LIKE', '%'.$attributs['locality'].'%')
                              ->where(DB::raw('CONCAT(address, " ", postal_code, " ", city)'), 'LIKE', '%'.$address.'%')
                              ->confirmed();
                    })
                    ->get();
```

Comment: SQL injection warning.. `DB::raw()` need to be manually protected with `DB::escape()` for example.

Comment: Tried, and it goes error 500, thoses if works, the thing I try to make is condition including, for example, name and adress, or specialty and adress